# Using Google Maps as "Overlay" on another Layout/View

Tags: android, layout, view, maps, overlay

I have a little problem.
My app has a surfaceview and displays the camera preview.
Now I want a map overlay. This overlay should be displayed in a corner of the display and show the current position of the user.

Here's a preview image of what I'd like to have:
[full res image](http://imageshack.us/a/img42/384/mapoverlay.jpg)

My problem is, that I don't know how to display a view/layout over another.
What I have at the moment is this as main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/CameraPreviewLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <FrameLayout
             android:id="@+id/SurfaceViewLayout"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MapsLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/Map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
     </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But this shows my preview layout with the + and - Button of the maps-layout.

Is it possible to get something like that? Cause I'm searching for a while now and find nothing.

Hope someone has an idea.

regards

**UPDATE:**
Here is my new `main_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/SurfaceViewLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/Map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you want that translucency effect, you are probably going to have to switch to directly using `MapView` instead of `MapActivity`, so you can try calling `setAlpha()` on it. Beyond that, are you loading the layout shown above directly in an activity (e.g., `setContentView()`) or from another fragment?

Comment: thanks for your answer.
the translucency effect is not that important. The map itself is more important.
yes, it's directly in my main-activity. I have not found a possibility to create a `View`, apply the second layout (with the `fragment`) to it and draw it on the canvas of the other layout. Or something like that

Comment: I've created a new `main_activity.xml` with a `RelativeLayout` (see update in OP), but now I only see the -/+ Buttons and the map itself is not visible.
If I set `android:layout_above="true" I see the map, but the `SurfaceView` is only using ~50% of the display size. Any idea how to fix that?